Python + Selenium; Trying to Match Specific Text to Variable and Click on the Found Element
SCREENSHOT OF WEB ELEMENT
I am trying to match a variable; in this case "Days_in_advance" where the output is the current date + 7 days, i.g. the 10th day of the month.
Am looking to match this "Days_in_advance" value with, text() to find the exact matching element and subsequently click on it.
Currently have something like this, highlighted row in screenshot is the value I'd like to match.

days_in_advance = date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = 7)
formatted_date = days_in_advance.strftime("%d")
datepick = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), formatted_date)]")
datepick.click()

I know this is wrong but I'm pretty new to this so I appreciate the help. Thanks!

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from datetime import date, timedelta

# Initialize the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the page containing the element
driver.get('URL_of_the_page')

# Calculate the date 7 days in advance
days_in_advance = date.today() + timedelta(days=7)
formatted_date = days_in_advance.strftime("%d")

# Print the formatted date for debugging
print(f"Formatted Date: {formatted_date}")

# Find the element containing the formatted date text and click it
xpath_expression = f"//*[contains(text(), '{formatted_date}')]"
datepick = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_expression)
datepick.click()

# Close the driver (if needed)
# driver.quit()

